# Implementation of ListenTo in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm not sure what this line does

```
      obj.on(name, typeof name === 'object' ? this : callback, this);
```

in the Backbone.js implementation of listenTo. I also understand that listenTo is a way of making one object act when another object responds to an event and I also see that the Backbone website says that the advantage of using listenTo is that if I destroy the original object then the other events acting on the other objects can be removed. How is that implemented as well in listenTo?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is the function signature of [`on`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on):

> object.on(event, callback, [context])

`event` is a either a an event name like "click" or an event map like this:

```
{
    'click .button': 'handler1',
    'keydown': function(){}
}
```

So inside the `listenTo` code you posted the first argument is the event name or event map. If it's an event name (type "string") you want to pass the specified callback as the second parameter to on. If `name` is an event map (type "object") Backbone passes `this` - it will eventually be used as a context, even though it was passed as a a callback.

Take a look at the `eventsApi` function and how it's invoked in `on`:

```
function(obj, action, name, rest) {
    if (!name) return true;
    if (typeof name === 'object') {
      for (var key in name) {
        obj[action].apply(obj, [key, name[key]].concat(rest));
      }
    }
// ... code in `on`:
eventsApi(this, 'on', name, [callback, context]) && callback)
```

Assume `name` is an event map (and thus `typeof name ==='object'` is true). For each member of the event map we call `on` with these arguments: `[key, name[key]].concat(rest)`. Since `rest` is `[callback, context]` we get four arguments.

But that's one more than `on` accepts - and the last one needs to be the context, not the `callback`. That's why `listenTo` passes the `this` object as the callback, which makes it the context of the event handler.

`listenTo` is a fairly new method, so I'm assuming that's why the variable names aren't meaningful.

---

When a view is removed - probably after the deletion of the model - the `remove` method calls `stopListening` on the view. That function just calls `off` on all handlers, if you don't pass it any arguments:

```
for (var id in listeners) {
    listeners[id].off(null, null, this);
}
```